# Crash on WKWebViewConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm currently working in integrating my company's SSO in our app, which should go through a WebView.

Before implementing it in the actual app, I made a separate project in which I managed to implement the whole thing and get the final token that I must pass along all requests in order for them to be identified by our proxy.

Anyways, initialising the WebView was no problem in the separate project. I did it in such way :

```
override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
```

Basically, I am instantiating the Webview the exact same way in my actual app. The only difference in the whole implementing process compared to how I did it in the separate one, is that we are working in MVP-C. Meaning that I have to go through a Coordinator and a Presenter to instantiate my WebViewController.

So far, it shouldn't be an issue, since I've done it for different cases over the past.

My issue is this one, whenever the call is made to instantiate the ViewController, that has to then display the WebView Controller, I get an EXC_BREAKPOINT on :

`let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()`

In this very specific case, there is no logs written in the console logs.

I have therefore tried different ways of implementing the whole thing, but I keep getting this crash without any details on why it's actually crashing.

I've seen posts about a compatibility issues back in 2020 between Mac M1 and iOS Deployment Targets below 14.0, but I'm running an M2 with iOS Deployment Target 16.2 (same as my separate project) with Ventura 13.0

So I'd like to pick on your brain on ways to debug this, or on actual solutions if you've ever encountered the issue.

Feel free to ask for more details,

Thanks in advance for the help.

Guigzer

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are replacing the controller's `.view` with a `WKWebView`, instead of adding the web view as a subview?

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure you are initializing the webview and it's configuration on the main thread? This is considered UI so needs to be on the main thread but often issues are hidden by obtuse errors or crashes with few leads on why something is going wrong.